# Finding users who will buy. Intractable Numbers

Tags: probability, python, expected-value

I'm facing the following problem. I think I have it formulated right, but unsure how to proceed. Here is the problem statement.
Assume there are $N$ users. For each user, I've an estimated probability that they would take an action. Call this $1- p_i$. Now the $p_i$ is a p-value, an output from a hypothesis test, that tests whether they would **not** take the action; hence the term $1-p_i$. So its not strictly the probability that the user would take an action. I want to estimate how many users in aggregate $T$ can I expect to take the action. A simplistic approach would be to simply sum up the probabilities
$$
T = \sum_{i}^{N}1\times (1-p_i)
$$
Would this be accurate? I'm concerned that the $p_i$'s are not strictly probabilities so the above summation would not yield the expected total.

Another approach I tried was the following. I replaced all the $p_i$ with an overall average $p$ (assume this is acceptable and their distributio is quite tight)/ The probability that at least one user would take an action is $1 - P(None)$ = $1 - p^{N}$. Likewise the probability that at least 2 users would take an action is $1- {N \choose 2} p^{2}$ and so on. For $k$ users to take the action, it works out to $1-{N\choose k}p^{k}$.
The first question I have is

1. Is the first / second method accurate?
2. If yes, how do I go about computing these large numbers that may come out of computing the ${N \choose k}p^{k}$

Comment: Work with logarithms instead.

Comment: @Sycorax applying logarithms wouldn't be straightforward. I would end up with $log(1- {n \choose k}p^{k}) $

Comment: Based on your description of the $p_i$ as p-values, it's unlikely anything you do with them will give meaningful information about the chances these people will "take action."  After all, p-values are probabilities *only under the assumed null hypothesis.*  Unless that assumption is true, your p-values don't describe anything about the real world.

Comment: This sounds like the Poisson binomial distribution if the $p_i$ are each treated as probabilities. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution